# How to include multiple import js file into another js file

Tags: javascript, salesforce-lightning

file constant.js

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import CONTACT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Contact';
import FIRSTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.FirstName';
import LASTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.LastName';
import EMAIL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Email';
import PHONE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Phone';
import FAX_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Fax';
```

file contact.js

```
export default class LdsCreateRecord extends LightningElement {

}
```

How can I include constant.js file in contact.js

for more clarification please visit this 
[Github](https://github.com/meta-gopal-gupta/Salesforce/pull/9#discussion_r424978674)

Comment: What do you export in constant.js?

Comment: I did not export anything
I had only mentioned other import statements

Comment: So why do you want to import it then? You will have to export it, you can't  reuse the imports like for example php. That is not how the import system works.

Comment: I want to use those constants into the contact.js file

Comment: Then you would have to import them again in your file(`contact.js`), you cannot reuse imports without exporting them again.

Comment: include('constants.js');
 this is also not working

Comment: https://github.com/meta-gopal-gupta/Salesforce/pull/9#discussion_r424978674

You can see this for problem clarification.

Comment: Is it just not possible, the way to handle import is to import them in the file you need them. There is no way to reuse it.

Comment: Please see the above link, I hope you will understand it.

Comment: I am not familiar with the project and thus cannot help you further. If you have any more questions create a new question with an isolated problem case.

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much for your valuable time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean "How can I include contact.js file in constant.js" then it is simple:

```js
import { LdsCreateRecord } from './contact.js';
```

If you mean what you said: "How can I include constant.js file in contact.js" then you must first export something from constant.js.

Comment: No 
I want reverse
I want to import contant.js in contact.js

I want to use all import statements(written in constant.js) in contact.js

Comment: @gopal how can you if constant.js doesn't export anything?

Comment: you can try adding the line `export { LightningElement, createRecord ShowToastEvent, ...}` to constant.js